# Different math font for captions in LaTeX

Tags: captions, titlesec, mathpazo

I have two fonts in my LaTeX (not XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX) document:

- Serif font: used in main text and math environment  (`mathpazo`).
- Sans-serif font: used in titles and captions (`pag`).

Math symbols in captions use the serif font. However, I would like them to use the sans-serif font. How could I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: I know, it cannot always be done, but would it not make sense just to omit any math in captions?

Comment: @OlegLobachev It would, but not in a scientific paper.

Comment: If it is a scientific paper, then you probably have a pre-defined style, and it would probably be a bad idea to change it.

Comment: @OlegLobachev No specific class in this particular case.

Comment: @OlegLobachev In addition, I just want to add some greek letters and similar symbols.

Comment: If you want Greek, you can add it as a regular (additional) language via `babel`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93832/discussion-between-baister-and-oleg-lobachev).